# Neo4j - WHERE negation on path not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (n:Owner) MATCH (v:Vehicles)
WHERE NOT (n)-[:OWNS]->(v)
RETURN  DISTINCT n.email, n.name ORDER BY n.name
```

and

```
MATCH (n:Owner) MATCH (v:Vehicles)
WHERE  (n)-[:OWNS]->(v)
RETURN  DISTINCT n.email, n.name ORDER BY n.name
```

is giving me the same result...What am I missing here?

On the other hand this works:

```
MATCH (n:Owner) MATCH (v:Vehicles)
WHERE NOT (n)-[:OWNS]-()
RETURN  DISTINCT n.email
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate nodes for any owners and/or vehicles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: This is an extension of @raj Answer, with more focus on the explaining issue.

This query is wrong and may return undesired results.

To understand take following example as data-set:

```
Owner       Vehicle
P1          V1
P2          V2
P3          V3
```

Since you are doing

```
MATCH (n:Owner) MATCH (v:Vehicles)
```

This results in Cartesian product for the two matches like this first 2 columns

```
Owner   Vehicle         NOT (n)-[:OWNS]->(v)    (n)-[:OWNS]->(v)

P1      V1              -                       P1
P2      V1              P2                      -
P3      V1              P3                      -
P1      V2              P1                      -
P2      V2              -                       P2
P3      V2              P3                      -
P1      V3              P1                      -
P2      V3              P2                      -
P3      V3              -                       P3
```

Now on filtering with `NOT (n)-[:OWNS]->(v)` gives (P1,P2,P3,P1,P2,P3)

Now on filtering with `(n)-[:OWNS]->(v) gives` (P1,P2,P3)

Now on returning distinct with `NOT (n)-[:OWNS]->(v)` gives (P1,P2,P3)

Now on returning distinct with `(n)-[:OWNS]->(v)` gives (P1,P2,P3)

Clearly these two are ending up being same right??

But note that this would only be true when all owners has at-least a vehicle and no owner owns all vehicle.

***So this is what you can do to find owners without vehicles.***

```
MATCH (a:Owner)
WHERE SIZE((a)-[:OWNS]->(:Vehicles)) = 0 
RETURN a
```

Comment: Nice explanation, I should have covered this.

Comment: Thanks I think you covered the topic clearly and simple. I did miss the possibility of the Cartesian product....There use to be a warning when you do this I don't see that warning anymore maybe Neo4j should look at  making it a standard warning.

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me.

It's recommended 
I think both `WHERE` and `Negation` are working as expected. And there is a high probability that both will give the same results.

**Let me tell you when both give the same results:**

> Both of these queries will give the same results when **all of the
>   `Owners` have at least one `Vehicle`** and **None of the `Owner` owns all the
>   `Vehicle`** in the database And There is a high probability that this
>   will be true in your case.

**I assume you want to find `users` who don't own any `Vehicle` and return their name and email. And in the second query, you want user who owns a `Vehicle` and return their name and email.**

If that's the case here are queries for same:

**1. Find `Owner` who don't own any `Vehicle`**

```
MATCH (n:Owner)
WHERE NOT (n)-[:OWNS]->(:Vehicles)
RETURN  DISTINCT n.email, n.name 
ORDER BY n.name
```

**2. `Owner` who owns a `Vehicle`**

```
MATCH (n:Owner)
WHERE (n)-[:OWNS]->(:Vehicles)
RETURN  DISTINCT n.email, n.name 
ORDER BY n.name
```

Comment: Brilliant finding on "all of the  Owners have at least one Vehicle and None of the Owner owns all the  Vehicle"!

Comment: This is a great holistic view of the use case...in my case only some owners had no car. @MissingNumbers had the explanation I was looking for.